# expected unqualified-id before '.' token in C++ and Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I try to create OldMcDonald song. When debugging, it shows an error in `main()`. Anyone can help to point out what the following error means?

> error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

It happens at this line:

```
OldMcDonald.sing();
```

Besides that, while debugging, I also found

> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

```
class Animal {
private:
    string _name;
    string _sound;
public:
Animal(string name, string sound){
    _name = name;
    _sound = sound;
}

    string getName(){
        return _name;
    }

    string getSound(){
        return _sound;
    }
};

class OldMcDonald {
private:
    Animal** _farm; // Old McDonald had a farm (still has now)
    const int _size; // Fixed farm size
public:
    OldMcDonald():_size(3) {
        _farm[0] = new Animal("cow","Moo");
        _farm[1] = new Animal("dog","Woof");
        _farm[2] = new Animal("duck","Quack");

    }
    ~OldMcDonald() {
        for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++){
            delete _farm[i];
        }
        delete[]_farm;
    }

    void sing() {
        for (int i=0; i<_size; i++) {
            cout << "Old McDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O\n";
            cout << "And on his farm he had a"" " <<_farm[i]->getName()<<", E-I-E-I-O\n";
            cout << "With a " <<_farm[i]->getSound()<<" "<<_farm[i]->getSound()<<" here and a " <<_farm[i]->getSound()<<" "<<_farm[i]->getSound()<<"there\n";
            cout << _farm[i]->getSound()<<" " "here"" " <<_farm[i]->getSound()<<" " "there, everywhere"" " <<_farm[i]->getSound()<<" "<<_farm[i]->getSound()<<"\n";
            cout << "Old McDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O";
        }
    }
};
int main(){
   OldMcDonald.sing();
}
```

Comment: change `OldMcDonald.sing();` to `OldMcDonald().sing();` 
You have to create an object to use one of its methods.

Comment: Please do not change the question after three answers pointing out to `OldMcDonald.sing();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your `sing()` method isn't `static`, so you are supposed to call it from an *instance* of `OldMcDonald`, not the *class type* itself.**

Example:

```
int main() {
  OldMcDonald bobby;
  bobby.sing();
}
```

---

If you make `sing()` a `static` member function:

```
static void sing();
```

...then you can call it using the class type, like this:

```
OldMcDonald::sing();
```

However, you won't have access to any of the member variables, since no instance of your class is passed to the method.

[**More information on static methods.**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you need to create an instance in order to call an instance method.

`OldMcDonald` is a class, i.e. a type. Singing is done by an instance, though, so you need this:

```
OldMcDonald mr;
mr.sing();
```

The idea behind class/instance distinction is that you can make many instances if your `OldMcDonald` class, and make all of them sing:

```
OldMcDonald mr, mrs, jr;
mr.sing();
mrs.sing();
jr.sing();
```

Answer (score 0):

The compile error is because `OldMcDonald` names a class here - not one of its instances.  You should instead write `OldMcDonald().sing()` which [value initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) a temporary instance and calls `sing` on it.

Also you do not initialize `_farm` in the constructor, so `_farm[0]=...` etc is writing to some arbitrary memory location, which is UB. You at least need to write `_farm = new Animal[3]`. However the [rule of three](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) applies here: if you pass an `OldMcDonald` instance to a function or copy assign one, then the destructor will eventually be run on both objects, double-freeing the data which is UB. For this reason you should most likely either use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or just delete the copy constructor and assignment operator.

(posted from phone; please pardon any misspellings)